# Как вручную настроить pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Сижу на Windows 10 x64

При установке питона есть дополнительная кнопочка, добавить питон в `Path`. Так вот, давно я это уже делал, уже успел наставить всяких пакетов через `pip`. Недавно решил попробовать запустить питон через `cmd`, запустил, прописав python, только вот запустился `python2`, вместо `python3`. Полез в `Path`, нашел расположения обеих версий питона, оказывается, названия обоих файлов `python.exe`. Для того, чтобы через консоль запускать нужную версию переименовал экзешники в `python2.exe` и `python3.exe`, все отлично через консоль стало работать.
Вернемся к нашим баранам. Решил я установить очередной пакет, а чёрта с два [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В pip же было указано, что название питона `python`, а не `python3`.
Вот что получается, либо нормально работает `pip`, либо консольный питон.

Возможно надо что-то вручную настраивать в `pip`?

Comment: `python<2|3> -m pip install ...`.

Comment: Сработало, но можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы как по-старинке через pip install заработало?

Comment: Для вызова нужной версии python можно запускать как `py -2 script.py` или `py -3 script.py`. Утилита py устанавливается вместе с python3 (начиная с версии 3.3), версию python2 поддерживает.

Answer (score 0):

Положить рядом с python3.exe тот же самый файл с названием python.exe.

Костыль, конечно, но работать должно.